# DOT Language Parser

Tags: c#

Does anyone know of a DOT Language (or other GraphViz-ish format)  Parser for .NET? 
I have been experimenting with QuickGraph, but it seems to only support serialization, and not parsing from a stream/string/file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Graphviz4Net](http://graphviz4net.codeplex.com/) core includes a DOT parser.

Comment: Updated the answer, this parser is great!

Answer (score 3):

Yet another DOT parser:

- Nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotParser/
- Sources: https://github.com/auduchinok/DotParser

Answer (score 2):

Well you could use a XML-based format like [GraphML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphML) which per se does not require its own parser, it also has xsd's [specified](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/specification.html) , so its rather trivial to add to .NET

Comment: Its the closest thing to a solution that anyone with this 'problem' will have. That is, next to Writing your own which wasnt hard.

Answer (score 2):

The [SPGraphviz](http://spgraphviz.codeplex.com/) project handles graph descriptions in `DOT`:

> **SPGraphviz** - create your own visualization graphs without programming in Sharepoint. Just define graph on **DOT language** in simple text file, upload it into document library and specify URL in SPGraphvizWebPart - it will make graphical representation of your graph

The [documentation](http://spgraphviz.codeplex.com/documentation) implies that the project uses a wrapper around the `C` language `graphviz`, and points to 2 such wrappers:

> `SPGraphvizWebPart` uses `Graphviz` open source library for rendering graphs defined on **DOT language**. Many objects in real life can be presented as a graph mathematical abstraction. E.g. organization structure, portal hierarchy, version history of the files, etc. - all these can be displayed as a graph (number of nodes with relations between them). Using DOT language you can create textual definition of a graph (nodes, relations, visual effects like color, shape, etc) in simple text file and pass this file into Graphviz library. It will make graphical representation of the graph using selected layout and image type.
>
> `Graphviz` - is library written on C. SPGraphviz uses managed wrapper for using functions from Graphviz library. There are several implementations of managed wrapper for Graphviz:
>
> - WinGraphviz by ood Tsen
> - Rendering an in-memory Graphviz image with C# by David Brown

Comment: Thank you, That seems to be  a solution but requires sharepoint?

Comment: The project is packaged for sharepoint, but you can extract the parts calling Graphviz from the source. Take a look in Graphviz.cs http://spgraphviz.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8015dcace5f0#SPGraphvizWebPart%2fCodeFiles%2fGraphviz.cs